# Multipoint Button Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to write a Button control which inherits from the `System.Windows.Controls.Button` class and reacts to MultipointMouse events (Microsoft Multipoint SDK). But for some reasons the mouse events are not recognized in the class. Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found an implementation of the MultipointButton in the SDK itself. So, there is no need for explicit implementation :)

Comment: please either remove this question or accept your own answer (and probably extend it)